# Where to find the package versions for the next Ubuntu release

Tags: package-management

I used to check the packages for a given Ubuntu version in package.ubuntu.com/versionname

For Ubuntu Eoan which will be released next year, I found [this page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/allpackages). However it shows an OpenCV version 3.2 which is the same as the OpenCV version in Ubuntu Bionic. Considering that Ubuntu Eoan will be released next year and that the current OpenCV versions are 3.4.6 and 4.1.0, this seems a bit odd.

So where are the package versions of an upcoming Ubuntu version discussed and decided/listed ?

EDIT:
my bad, Ubuntu Eoan is 19.10 and not 20.04 as I thought. My question is still holding though, who decides which package versions come to an ubuntu release and where is that discussed?

Comment: In the lifecycle of release, multiple freezes are done. As of now only Toolchain has been updated. If you download ISO for 19.10, you mean even see wallpaper and theme identical to 19.04, So, at this point of time there is very little difference in 19.04 and 19.10. Read [EoanErmine/ReleaseSchedule - Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EoanErmine/ReleaseSchedule)

Comment: You can also monitor https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/eoan-changes/2019-May/date.html, and https://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=427

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Debian and Ubuntu Developers Decide:**

Most Ubuntu packages are imported from Debian sources. The process in Ubuntu is called "Debian Import" and occurs during the [first four months of a release cycle](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EoanErmine/ReleaseSchedule).

Debian Import ends (with a few exceptions) at Debian Import Freeze, typically two months before release.

Whatever version is in [Debian sid gets imported](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebianImportFreeze) to Ubuntu.

Discussion happens in several places: IRC, mailing lists, and discourse.ubuntu.com.

**Talking to developers about upgrading a package is generally a waste of time**. They already know. Instead, the best way to get newer packages into Ubuntu is by participation: Help developers test and debug the newer packages in both Debian Experimental and later in Ubuntu pre-release.

For the example you gave of OpenCV, three different versions (3.3, 3.4, and 4.0) are all in Debian Experimental. The highest version that stops crashing and migrates to Debian Sid before Ubuntu's Debian Import Freeze (22 Aug, 2019) is likely to be in Ubuntu 19.10. More help testing and debugging makes it more likely a higher version will make it into Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, however few points are still not clear. Where are the current experimental packages listed? And where do those discussions happen? All I could find were non archived mailing lists or archived mailing lists with no search option.

Comment: The Debian maintainer of OpenCV is the Debian Science Team. Here's [DST's list of packages](https://qa.debian.org/developer.php?login=debian-science-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org) and their [mailing list archive](https://alioth-lists.debian.net/pipermail/debian-science-maintainers/)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [user535733's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1142902/26246), below a general instructions to check any package pipeline status.

1. Go to https://packages.ubuntu.com and search for *source* package (`OpenCV`)
2. Select the target release (`eoan`)
3. There in the *source package page* you find all related links:

   - Package page in Launchpad: Ubuntu Resources > Bug Reports

     You can find which version was imported and when.
   - Original imported source: Ubuntu Resources > Debian Source Repository (Git)

     You can find last stable and experimental branches and uploads, which may get imported to Ubuntu soon or later,
   - Ubuntu maintainer

     MOTU team has public online meetings, but i don't expect discussing such regular process for specific package.
   - Original maintainer
   - Upstream official project

Also, for relatively fast releasing project you may not able to find any PPA for edge release.

- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas